# Fast reliable e-mail clients for OS X

Tags: macos, mac, email

I have about 8gb of e-mail from about 10 years. I have my structure organized into a lot of folders. I am on 10.6.2, 8gb RAM and a SSD drive.

I am on OS X and using Apple Mail. It works ok. Generally not as fast as I would like.

I have used Entourage in the past and is just slow and bloated. I have had a lot of database issues.

I have used Evolution on Linux before and been happy.

I have tried Sylpheed and I dont recall why I did not like it.

Thunderbird has always been slow and quirky for me.

Eudora is dead. (except crappy sponsored mode)

What are options for fast e-mail clients that have advanced filtering and can deal with a large amount of e-mail?

Anything MySQL driven?

Comment: So, 10 years of email, then you might care about easy backup *and* easy restore. If you want a Time-Machine-aware mail client, then Mail.app is your one and only friend.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Postbox](http://www.postbox-inc.com)

I've only given it a quick go, but it looks promising.

Comment: $40, that's more then Snow Leopard! Though I haven't looked at it at all, nice find.

Answer (score 1):

You should give a try to new [Thunderbird 3](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/). I've been using it since launch and really happy about performance and UI.

Answer (score 0):

I found Mail to be the best compromise. I had previously used Thunderbird but was dissatisfied with the speed and reliability of it. Other then using a web based client (Gmail being a great one) there isn't a whole lot of options for Apple based email clients.

A couple of other clients for you to consider:

1. [Mulberry](http://www.mulberrymail.com/) (old)
2. [Mailsmith](http://www.mailsmith.org/)
3. [GNUMail](http://www.collaboration-world.com/gnumail)

All of them are pretty old and I doubt they will offer you anything Mail doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

There’s such a paucity of decent options, some Mac developers are attempting an open-source project to make an e-mail app called [Letters](http://inessential.com/2010/01/18/letters_email_app_update).